# Most efficient way to throttle continuous JavaScript execution on a web page

Tags: javascript, dom-events, throttling

I'd like to continuously execute a piece of JavaScript code on a page, spending all available CPU time I can for it, but allowing browser to be functional and responsive at the same time.

If I just run my code continuously, it freezes the browser's UI and browser starts to complain. Right now I pass a zero timeout to `setTimeout`, which then does a small chunk of work and loops back to `setTimeout`. This works, but does not seem to utilize all available CPU. Any better ways of doing this you might think of?

**Update:** To be more specific, the code in question is rendering frames on `canvas` continuously. The unit of work here is one frame. We aim for the maximum possible frame rate.

Comment: That's because most browsers don't allow a javascript interval of 0ms.  They cap it at 20ms or something like that.

Comment: This seems like a pretty bad idea in general, but maybe not for your purposes. Can you tell us about what your code that you're running constantly is doing?

Comment: @hobberwickey: It's rendering graphics on canvas and aims for the highest possible frame rate.

Comment: @JosephMarikle—not quite. IE 8 (and all previous versions as far as I know) has  minimum "tick" of about 15ms. Many other browsers will tick as often as they can, Firefox typically 2ms but maybe as long as 10ms when the system is more or less idle.

Comment: @RobG, according to HTML5 browsers are supposed to have a minimum interval of 4 milliseconds. (See [7.3 step 5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers) and the [Mozilla Developer Wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=window.setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting)). Chrome actually tried doing a faster interval, and it broke the web. Therefore, Chrome (and other browsers) put a minimum on their delays.

Comment: @NathanWall: Very useful references! And turned out it's even possible to change this value in Firefox in `about:config` (dom.min_timeout_value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use `window.postMessage()` to overcome the limitation on the minimum amount of time `setTimeout` enforces. See [this article](http://dbaron.org/log/20100309-faster-timeouts) for details. A demo is available [here](http://dbaron.org/mozilla/zero-timeout).

Answer (score 3):

Probably what you want is to centralize everything that happens on the page and use requestAnimationFrame to do all your drawing. So basically you would have a function/class that looks something like this (you'll have to forgive some style/syntax errors I'm used to Mootools classes, just take this as an outline)

```
var Main = function(){
   this.queue = [];
   this.actions = {};

   requestAnimationFrame(this.loop)
}

Main.prototype.loop = function(){
   while (this.queue.length){
       var action = this.queue.pop();
       this.executeAction(e);
   }

   //do you rendering here
   requestAnimationFrame(this.loop);
}

Main.prototype.addToQueue = function(e){
   this.queue.push(e);
}

Main.prototype.addAction = function(target, event, callback){
    if (this.actions[target] === void 0) this.actions[target] = {};
    if (this.actions[target][event] === void 0) this.actions[target][event] = [];

    this.actions[target][event].push(callback);
}

Main.prototype.executeAction = function(e){
    if (this.actions[e.target]!==void 0 && this.actions[e.target][e.type]!==void 0){
        for (var i=0; i<this.actions[e.target][e.type].length; i++){
            this.actions[e.target][e.type](e);
        }
    }
}
```

So basically you'd use this class to handle everything that happens on the page. Every event handler would be `onclick='Main.addToQueue(event)'` or however you want to add your events to your page, you just point them to adding the event to the cue, and just use Main.addAction to direct those events to whatever you want them to do. This way every user action gets executed as soon as your canvas is finished redrawing and before it gets redrawn again. So long as your canvas renders at a decent framerate your app should remain responsive.

EDIT: forgot the "this" in requestAnimationFrame(this.loop)

Comment: Thank you. But did you mention `onclick`? Would I have to make user click things on the page all the time for the code to advance? I don't quite understand how and when the code would actually be executed there. I need the webpage to run without any user interaction - the user just sits back and watches.

Comment: Right, you put the animation rendering code where I indicated and if you want other things to happen (like users clicking on things, or whatever else they would do on the page) you use addToQueue to trigger them. If the user's not doing anything the animation just plays.

Comment: Yes, but what re-triggers the animation? That is, after we've rendered one frame, we would need to stop (so the browser could handle the UI etc). After that we would like to be called to render another frame - what would trigger that call?

Comment: that's what requestAnimationFrame(this.loop) does.

Comment: Ah, right -- I did not realize it was an existing API function.

Comment: Here's a good article on it http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Answer (score 2):

web workers are something to try

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers
```

Comment: Thanks! This may be applicable - however, the code is drawing on the page, which is probably not what a worker can do. I would expect the worker would have to communicate all results to the UI thread, which would add extra work both for the programmer and for the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can tune your performance by changing the amount of work you do per invocation. In your question you say you do a "small chunk of work". Establish a parameter which controls the amount of work being done and try various values.

You might also try to set the timeout **before** you do the processing. That way the time spent processing should count towards any minimum the browsers set.

One technique I use is to have a counter in my processing loop counting iterations. Then set up an interval of, say one second, in that function, display the counter and clear it to zero. This provides a rough performance value with which to measure the effects of changes you make.

In general this is likely to be very dependent on specific browsers, even versions of browsers. With tunable parameters and performance measurements you could implement a feedback loop to optimize in real-time.

Comment: Thanks, that's another solution. The hard part here is that this requires calibration. The load on the user's machine may change over time, which would make such a calibration brittle. Also, ideally I would just render one frame, then yield to browser for it to handle its events, then render another frame right away, and so on. That is, the unit of work here is one frame - it's hard to make that unit smaller or larger.

Comment: Indeed, you understand the difficulties. I would add a parameter to control the number of frames per invocation. The issue is the relative processing per frame versus the time spent by the browser when there is nothing to do. Both clearly depend on a multitude of factors some of which can vary continuously.